# Slash command not registered - DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body, 0.options[2].type: This field is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot that has a slash command; `/info`. My intention is to have a subcommand - `server` - execute without needing to specify a value.

This code, however, does not allow me to do that. It instead throws an error upon bot startup.

```js
const { Client, CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");

module.exports = {
    ...new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("info")
    .setDescription("Displays information regarding the current server or specified user")
    .addUserOption((option) => option
        .setName("user")
        .setDescription("Displays information regarding the specified user")
    )
    .addUserOption((option) => option
        .setName("member")
        .setDescription("Displays information regarding the specified guild member")
    )
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) => subcommand
        .setName("server")
        .setDescription("Displays information regarding the current server")
    ),
// ...
```

**Error**

```
F:\GitHub\Discord Bots\Bailey-v4\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
0.options[2].type: This field is required
    at RequestHandler.execute (F:\GitHub\Discord Bots\Bailey-v4\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (F:\GitHub\Discord Bots\Bailey-v4\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildApplicationCommandManager.set (F:\GitHub\Discord Bots\Bailey-v4\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ApplicationCommandManager.js:146:18)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (F:\GitHub\Discord Bots\Bailey-v4\handler\index.js:44:9)
```

Assistance (in any) would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can mix the `addSubcommand()` method with other methods like  `addUserOption()`. Sub-command and sub-command group option types are mutually exclusive to all other types.

To solve this, you will need to set up two more sub commands:

```js
new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('info')
  .setDescription(
    'Displays information regarding the current server or specified user',
  )
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
      .setName('user')
      .setDescription('Displays information regarding the specified user')
      .addUserOption((option) =>
        option.setName('target')
          .setDescription('The user')
          .setRequired(true),
      ),
  )
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
      .setName('member')
      .setDescription('Displays information regarding the specified guild member')
      .addUserOption((option) =>
        option
          .setName('target')
          .setDescription('The member')
          .setRequired(true),
      ),
  )
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
      .setName('server')
      .setDescription('Displays information regarding the current server'),
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I receive the error:
`DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body`
`0.options[0].type: This field is required`
`0.options[1].type: This field is required`
`0.options[2].type: This field is required`

Comment: Could you post your whole file on a site like pastebin.com and send the link here in a comment?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1cSamLPC

Comment: And what do you do with the exported object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but the repository for this bot is here: https://github.com/Skyslaw/Bailey-v4.1

Comment: @Bailey It's a 404 page for me. I don't think your repo is public.

Comment: There; it should be public now.